# AmCharts addLabel Font Size Not Working

Tags: amcharts

No matter how I use this addLabel method, the font size will not work!

`chart.addLabel(0, '50%', 'No data available for this client', 'center', 30);
chart.addLabel(0, '50%', 'No data available for this client', 'center', '30px');
chart.addLabel(0, '50%', 'No data available for this client', 'center', '30');`

The label itself works, but the size will not change. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce it but it works for me (the first option). Could it be you have some custom CSS that overrides the font-size of the `<text>` node?

Comment: Yes! You are correct! Thank you!